# Is the word 'honky' still used only pejoratively?

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

I know that historically *honky* was a pejorative term for a white person and that it may still be so but there is a 1973 song by the British band called Vinegar Joe titled ['Proud to be (a Honky Woman)'](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=28776) where this word is clearly used in a desirable sense.

Is this a one-off or have the attributes of the word changed?

Comment: What research have you yourself done? Do dictionaries normally flag the word?

Comment: All of the online dictionaries that I've looked at list it as pejorative only

Comment: That information (with names of those dictionaries) needs adding to your question.

Comment: I'm not interested in what the dictionaries have to say but in what current usage may be as dictionaries usually take some time to acknowledge this.

Comment: I understood that it was intended to be the equivalent of 'nigger' for white people (and to be used mainly by black people). I believe that it was based on the word for 'white' in an African language which, since the N word is based on the Latin for 'black' gave it a symmetry of origin. As a white person I considered that the introduction of 'honky' was quite  reasonable, however it doesn't seem to have taken off, which is a pity in my opinion. I have heard black people using the N word ironically to refer to themselves, the use of the H word by a white person seems to be equivalent.

Comment: 'I'm not interested in what the dictionaries have to say but in what current usage may be' sounds very laudable but is an invitation for unauthoritative speculation and opinion. Dictionaries, while imperfect, are usually the best we've got. They do unbiased and large-scale surveys.

Comment: In the song she doesn't seem to be using it in a racial context. She seems to be using it with a meaning of disregarding social norms or etiquette e.g. she says she smokes cigarettes in bed. So a honky person is someone who defies social convention whenever it would prevent them from behaving true to themselves.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, thanks for your comment Edwin but the dictionaries are, as you say, imperfect and do not seem to have the answer. I am interested in people saying that they have come across it being used in a non-pejorative sense in other contexts.

Comment: ChrisM Your comment about the content of the lyrics would be better edited into the question. I didn't find any lyrics online (but I didn't look very hard, admittedly). That said, @BoldBen's hypothesis of a reclamation of *honky,* similar to how *queer* was reclaimed from being a pejorative epithet by its target community, seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the lyrics are impossible to find without having to sign up to a website and, presumably, thence getting spammed to death.

Comment: There is a vast difference between using such terms to refer to oneself and  to refer to others. I'd say that using the term to refer to others could always potentially give rise to litigation.

Comment: My impression has always been that it's only mildly pejorative.  And, of course, the word is used in contexts such as "honky-tonk" where it might imply "lower-class", but has no strong racial overtones.

Comment: Okay, here's a non-pejorative use for you: *my sister  is a honky and a cracker and she's proud of it; so am I*. Can we move on?

Comment: It's not uncommon for a group of people to appropriate a term that's used derogatorily towards them by outsiders. Blacks can call each other "nigger" and it's not derogatory, but a white man can't. Similarly, if a white person calls themselves a "honky", it's not the same as a black person doing it. There's often a sense of irony in the use.

Answer (score 1):

The most common meaning of *honky* is "white person". According to [Communicating offense: the sordid life of language use](http://www.academia.edu/2840336/Communicating_offense_the_sordid_life_of_language_use):

> …the word “honky” is a derogatory term for a Caucasian. Anyone who claims to be using it in a non-derogatory sense is also making a linguistic error.

---

There is, however, another definition for *honky* (noun):

> Freq. with capital initial. An immigrant from central or eastern Europe, *esp.* one working as a manual labourer. Hence occas. more generally: any person employed in manual or unskilled work.
>   <sub>oed.com</sub>

This definition is "rare" and "chiefly historic in later use". It may not seem offensive, but it was often used alongside other slurs like dago, wop, and bohunk.

Between the two definitions, OED says it's "chiefly derogatory".

Answer (score -3):

My understanding is that this has nothing to do with the colour of the person's skin. It reflects the class status i.e. she is a working-class/lower class woman.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, dave. On ELU, the aim is to provide answers which are supported by authoritative references. Reputable dictionaries carry out extensive research to avoid answers that are overly subjective. Idiolects may well reflect different local practices, but dictionaries' usage panels will be far better placed to speak on idiomaticity across broader English-speaking domains.